# Unique IDs between Users and Admins with Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have installed Devise and created Users and also Admins using Option 1 from this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role

Now I need a little help. When adding the Admins it creates a different table, and the potential arises that the admins and regular users could have the same ID's.

So how exactly do I got about grabbing information from users and admins? Say for example I want to display all users? Do I have to traverse the users table and then the admins table?

Or if I am displaying a post. How will I know which table to look for to get the user or admin info?

I know I can just add a role column to the users table but I wanted to avoid this.

I hope this makes sense haha

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I highly recommend using the Single Table Inheritance (STI). You could do the STI by adding a column named `type` with a `string` datatype in the `users` table and create an `admin` model as well as a `normal_user` model both models will inherit from the `user` model of the `devise` gem.

```
class NormalUser < User
end

class Admin < User
end
```

The type column is a reserved word which will hold a value either `NormalUser` or `Admin` according to the user type you created.

To create an admin use `Admin.create(...)` and to create a normal user use `NormalUser.create(...)` where the dots are the attributes of the `Admin` and the `NormalUser`

Comment: @mohammed.magdy Awesome I think this is what I was looking for. Could you help me in setting up the proper authentication code. I am attempting to use Rails_Admin so I need a way to authenticate admins.

Comment: Sure, in the users table, you added a column named type which is a string datatype. The value of the type column will be either Admin or NormalUser (in our case here). When a user is logged in, you could get the type of the user by adding a method in the user.rb that checks the signed in user type. For the admin define a method named admin? the body will be self.is_a?(Admin) this will return true if the signed in user is admin else will return false. Same for the NormalUser, in the user.rb file add a method named def normal_user? the body of the method will be self.is_a?(NormalUser).

Comment: For Authentication, I recommend using cancan gem but the devise will work for you in both authorization and authentication if the roles are not too much.

Comment: great thanks alot for your help. I have successfully created the STI and am working on setting up authorization.