# Multiple users with devise in the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a problem, i need create 3 type of users with devise. these users have different fields. I thought about creating a table but would have many blank fields.

any recommendations? I'm very confused. I need a tutorial :)

Thanks friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something called Single Table Inheritance. Basically you create one user model with devise which has a column "type" which is a string and you create sub models, like

`class Admin < User
 end`

```
Class CMS < User
end
```

etc....

Also, put all the common attributes in the User model

Look at these links for an in-depth explanation. STI is the solution. That much is sure

http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

[devise and multiple "user" models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models)

[Unique IDs between Users and Admins with Devise Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450477/unique-ids-betweens-users-and-admins-with-devise-rails/9452181)

[Rails 4 Devise Multiple User Models STI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064649/rails-4-devise-multiple-user-models-sti)

Stackoverflow ppl has already dealt with STI extensively!

Hope these helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use STI mechanism...
or you can separate all tables with use of devise